# Shopify - Modify Page Template & Sections Reference For Custom Page

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am attempting to modify a specific route/template in my Shopify theme, however nothing from examples I have seen or the documentation seems to take.

Currently I have created a page in the Shopify Admin team which is auto assigned to the route `/pages/team-page`.

In my `templates` directory I have tried creating different variations as to assign it a custom section such as

- team.json
- team_page.json
- page.team.json
- page.team_page.json

And within those json files referenced to my `sections` directory liquid file `custom.liquid` with the following:

```
{
  "sections": {
    "custom": {
      "type": "custom",
      "settings": {}
    },
    "order": [ "custom" ]
}
```

But to no avail it always references back to the template `index.json` which renders `main.liquid` from sections.

Attempting to print out the `page.handle` returns `team-page`, while `page.template_suffx` seems to return nothing.

Comment: Did you assign the page to that specific template? That can be done in the admin page. To manually use the template you can visit `/pages/team-page?view=team` if the template file is `page.team.liquid`

Comment: @fabiofili2pi The query param was a new trick, very helpful. 

You were correct about assigning it in the admin. If you would like to create an answer on how to do that, to reflect what you have in your local environment I will accept the answer.